# Passing dynamically generated values to ERC20 Constructor

Tags: blockchain, solidity, erc20, decentralized-applications

## Issue

Hi everyone!
I'm currently working on an website that autogenerates ERC20 token by the value supplied by user. The biggest concern i've been getting is passing user values to ERC20 constructor since it expects two arguments in the constructor which is `_name` and `_symbol` and i dont want this to be hardcoded into the smart contract since it depends largely on the value input by user.

## Attempt I

I try to overwrite the two values from openzepellin ERC20 but to no avail, i got a token deployed with no name

#### Token.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract DamiKing is ERC20 {
address public admin;
string name;
string symbol;

event serverStatus(string serverMessage);
constructor() ERC20(name, symbol) 
payable {

    _name = name;
    _symbol = symbol;
    _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    admin = msg.sender;
}
```

#### deploy.js

```
async function main() {
const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
const DMKContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("DamiKing");
const DMKContract = await DMKContractFactory.deploy("damilare", "afo");
const x = await DMKContract.deployed();
console.log("Smart Contract Deployed with the address: ",DMKContract.address);
console.log("Total Suppy: ",await DMKContract.checkBalance(owner.address), await 
DMKContract.symbol());
console.log("owner address: ", owner.address);
console.log(x)
}
```

---

## Attempt II

I tried to pass a variable name to the ERC20 constructor so i can supply that during deployment but i got an error of `Expected ',' but got 'memory'solidity(2314)`

#### Token.sol

```
    constructor() ERC20(string memory name, string memory symbol) payable {
    _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    admin = msg.sender;
}
```

## Attempt III

I tried to ignore the constructor of ERC20 and focus mainly on my contract constructor, that end up badly with an error of `Contract "DamiKing" should be marked as abstract.`

```
 constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) payable {
    _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    admin = msg.sender;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, i've been stuck for weeks!

Comment: you should specify the version of the OpenZeppelin contracts package you are using.  Also, in general, their implementations have name, symbol, etc stored as private variables in a parent class.  So you need to pass these values into their constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to make sure if I understood it right, You are making a website that takes inputs from user, i.e token Name and Token Symbol, and deploys an erc20 token based on that. If that the case.

You can achieve this by using the Factory pattern. I found a random git by doing a simple google search, [you can see the code here](https://github.com/samc621/TokenFactory/blob/master/contracts/Factory.sol).

Comment: Thanks, i got the hint needed with this repo you gave, Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to always write the arguments inside `constructor(...)`. In this case the arguments are only `name` and `symbol`. They must be passed in the ERC20 constructor (you can see it from openzeppelin's code), and not defined again in your contract.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract DamiKing is ERC20 {
    address public admin;

    event serverStatus(string serverMessage);

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
        admin = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was missing, thanks!